# wkhtmltopdf not creating pdf from PHP code

Tags: php, html, pdf, cmd, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to create PDF from HTML using wkhtmltopdf, However when I do it using PHP script It doesn't create PDF but when I paste that same command on terminal it generates the pdf, don't know what's happening.

```
$html_file_url = 'http:127.0.0.1/assessment/testreport.html';
$pdf_file_base_url = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\assessment'; 

$slash = '\\';
$user = $_SESSION['email'];
$pdf = '.pdf';
$pdf_file_url = $pdf_file_base_url.$slash.$user.$pdf;

$cmd = 'C://xampp//htdocs//assessment//wkhtmltopdf//bin//wkhtmltopdf --page-height 193.14583333 --page-width 157.42708333 --javascript-delay 3000 --
cookie PHPSESSID np6btqg4lvr02k62us9pbcrote http://127.0.0.1/assessment/testreport.html C://xampp//htdocs//assessment//work7.pdf';
exec($cmd);
echo $cmd;
```

Currently the command stored in $cmd variable is the one using which I am able to generate report from terminal. (Above variables are just those using which I was creating customised URL so currently they do not play any role)

Also It doesn't give any error just echoes my command.

Comment: Have you tried defining a output and dump it to see what your command is returning? `exec($cmd, $output)` https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php

Comment: On your suggestion I did this and it returned **output: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => [14] => )**

Comment: And have you tried [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.shell-exec.php) ?

Comment: Just tried, but again nothing :(

Comment: @KJ I tried the highlighted too and it is not working, also I didn't get security switch part would you mind explaining in detail? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier and KJ This is the error I am getting when I added **2>&1**  --------  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P3pYa2OSYAk2FiSnQG4HkX5Ww8UlgNS_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KJ  Now when I see I don't think this is an error rather it is the content which is there in wkhtmltopdf documentation

Comment: @KJ I don't know why but after adding this now page is going in infinite load and whole application got stuck in loading, had to restart xampp . Also about syntax error in --cookie I don't think there's any because as I mentioned it is working fine on terminal

Comment: @KJ    I tried both the things you mentioned but nothing seems to work, I am almost giving up on this. Can you suggest something which can generate pdf from HTML but server side not on a button click or something in client side

Comment: Hi @KJ, I actually noticed something in my apache error logs. It goes like this **loading page http://127.0.0.1/assessment/testreport.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to http error: 1001** . Do you know anything related to this?